# angular: update directive when injected factory change data

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angularjs-factory

I have a directive that gets its data from a factory. It works fine, when loads first time. But later, when the factory data changed, directive do not react on this changes. How can i fix it?

```
appWD.directive('widgetName', ['WidgetData', function(WidgetData) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '_widget.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.data = WidgetData.GetWidgetData('widgetName');
            //both do not work
            //scope.$watch(scope.data);
            //scope.$watch(WidgetData.GetWidgetData('widgetName'));
        }
    };
}]);
```

GetWidgetData('widgetName') returns object.

codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwLLxM?editors=101

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
scope.$watchCollection(function(){return WidgetData.getWidgetData('widget');}, function() {
    alert('scope.$watchCollection');
 });
```

$watchCollection "shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of the properties change" [AngularJs Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

I created a small app to replicate your problem. Here is the [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDmmaXcRLb5upE0JJSep)

Comment: There was an issue in your watchCollection. I changed the code in my answer and also created a demo.

Comment: Also here is the working version of http://codepen.io/uslperera/pen/epEEMx?editors=101

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.$apply()
},0);
```

put this after data updation, this vl update UI
May work